# New 14.04 Install on Workstation - Suggish Performance

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, dell, performance

Machine Details

Dell Precision M4800 Laptop

Intel i7-4900MQ

Nvidia Quadro K2100

16GB Memory

240GB SSD

Hi,
I was running Windows 8 for a while but finally decided to make the switch to Ubuntu.
I installed 14.04 on a 2nd SSD Hard disk and apart from some issues with the graphics card everything went well. Ran this setup for a couple of days (dual booting with Win8) and it was great.

I then decided to format the machine and install 14.04 as the only OS. Applied same fixes for Nvidia card but the machine is sluggish. It feels as if it running on 2gb or ram not 16gb. Opening up Chrome can take up to 10 seconds - launching any other app takes almost as long.

It also seems to stutter - so If I'm typing away it will choke then put what ive written on the screen.

Any pointers on where to look would be great as googling for the last 12 hours hasnt helped.

p.s. Dell have disabled the Nvidia Optimus at a hardware level - so the laptop only runs on the main card. Not sure if related

Comment: Just an update to this: The issue was with a 130W Power Adaptor rather than the 180W that was supplied with the system. During the install I decided to update the BIOS - and it would seem that using the latest BIOS performance is capped when using a lower wattage power adaptor.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update to this:

The issue was with a 130W Power Adaptor rather than the 180W that was supplied with the system. During the install I decided to update the BIOS (which reset all settings)- and it would seem that using the latest BIOS performance is capped when using a lower wattage power adaptor.

The culprit it Intel Speed-Step. If it detects a lower wattage then it will cap your processor at around half the power.

If you frequently use a smaller power adaptor (smaller = less wattage = lighter to carry (180w weighs over 1kg)) - then you can simply go into your bios settings > Performance > Intel Speed-Step > Disable.

Please note - while the smaller power adapter will power your machine it will probably struggle to charge your battery while the machine is on !